# Apache Flink 1.4 with Apache Kafka 1.0.0

Tags: apache-kafka, sbt, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to get Apache Flink Scala project to integrate with Apache Kafka 1.0.0.  When i attempt to add the flink-connector-kafka package in my build.sbt file I get an error saying it cannot resolve it.

When i then look at the options available in the maven repository, there is no maven dependency available for Apache Kafka 2.11-1.0.0 for any version above 0.10.2

```
val flinkVersion = "1.4.1"
val flinkDependencies = Seq(
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided")
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka" % flinkVersion)
```

Does anyone know how to integrate these versions correctly so that I can connect Apache Flink 1.4 to Apache Kafka 2.11-1.0.0, as nothing I seem to try works (and i do not wish to downgrade the Kafka version I am connecting to).

Comment: 0.10.2 Kafka clients are compatible with 1.0.0 brokers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. Try:

```
val flinkVersion = "1.4.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka-0.11" % flinkVersion
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

`org.apache.flink" % "flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11" % "1.4.0`

`flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11` is Flink's latest Kafka connector available.

Sources: https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cflink%20kafka%20connector , https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.flink%22%20AND%20a%3A%22flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11%22

A Kafka 1.0 broker is backwards compatible with 0.11 and 0.10 APIs.